What to do if I had sex during menses with knowledge that it is haram?
I had sex with my husband during menses as I was going to be in long distance from him for a few years and I wanted a child.
I didn't get pregnant still but what is the amount of money I should give in charity for having sex during periods?

Please ask one question per post.
